# Is my ItemsSource syntax ok?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource

I have the following XAML.  Let's say FruitList is a collection of Fruits, each of which has a collection of FruitSeeds.  Is there a syntax to bind cbxFruitSeeds to a collection of FruitSeeds, depending on which Fruit is selected in cbxFruits?

```
<GridView>

    <GridViewColumn Header="Fruits">

        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Fruit.Name" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.FruitList}" x:Name="cbxFruits"/>

            </DataTemplate>

    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

</GridViewColumn>

    <GridViewColumn Header="FruitSeeds">

        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <ComboBox x:Name="cbxFruitSeeds"></ComboBox>

            </DataTemplate>

        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

    </GridViewColumn>

</GridView>
```

Comment: You really need to ask a specific question here.

Comment: You could use a collection view on the second combobox and use the first combobox to control filtering on the second. Because honestly, you don't need to store which kind of fruit the user wants, but which kind of seed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do a cascading combobox.

[Is there really no way to follow up dataset parent relation in xaml binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202990/is-there-really-no-way-to-follow-up-dataset-parent-relation-in-xaml-binding) shows how to do a parent-child set up in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this the right way.

1. Setup a collection view as the source for the second combobox, then setup the first combobox to alter the filter on that collection view.
2. Have the datatype for the items for the first combobox each contain a list of items for the second combobox. When the first combobox is selected, its result is set as the second's data context, then bind the second to the contained list.

The first is preferable because you don't need to store the fruit type in the data that saves the user's choice. The first combobox is populated by a config, or metadata.